# Button with right arrow

Tags: android, xml, button, material-design, android-cardview

I am trying to make a button with right arrow in it.
I have defined a card view with a button inside it. but I am not sure how I can put the arrow along with it and if its possible to achieve in xml.
Button should look like this :

[image]

My xml looks like this :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/signupCard"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loginCard"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="@string/signUp"
        android:textColor="#DE000000" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use this layout.
It will work for your case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/signupCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d5dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/d10dp">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/d50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/d30dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/icon_right_aero_black"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#DE000000" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: CardView Inside Button with Right aero]

Comment: For FontFamily, you can add android:fontFamily="<your_font_file>" property in .xml layout of Button and set android:textAllCaps="false".

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :
you can get that image by right click **Drawable** > **New** > **Vector** **Asset** > **Clip Art**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signup"
    ...
    android:drawableRight="your image"
    ...
    android:textColor="#DE000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `android:drawableRight` inside xml and just for information this property can also assigned to the view programatically for that yo have to use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int)`
here params arre

`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int /*FOR LEFT DRAWABLE*/,int/*FOR TOP DRAWABLE*/,int/*FOR RIGHT DRAWABLE*/,int/*FOR BOTTOM DRAWABLE*/)`

if you don't want to set `drawable` then pass `0` in to it

so for know you just use first method  inside the xml  using `android:drawableRight`  property

Answer (score 0):

You can use button drawable right or drawable end property to set image:
Also, you can use padding property to apply padding to a drawable image.

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/imgButton"
      android:text="imageButton"
      android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_image"
      android:drawableEnd="@drawable/your_image"
      android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
      android:textColor="@color/colorButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can go buddy,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple you can 
First of all you need a vector icon which you an get from official google website
[Material Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) .

then you will get a rar while which you can extract each type of drawable to the mipmap folders of your android project

files you will get from rar file are

> drawable-hdpi
>   ,drawable-mdpi
>   ,drawable-xhdpi
>   ,drawable-xxhdpi
>   drawable-xxxhdpi

copy images containing in this folders in mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi and mipmap-xxxhdpi respectively

now you have got icon now do following

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Login"
android:background="@color/white"
android:drawableRight="@mipmap/yourIconName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res- 
                         auto"
                        android:id="@+id/cardview1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:foreground="? 
                        android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/White"
                        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
                        card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
                        card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
                        card_view:contentPadding="7dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="5dp">



                            <TextView
                                style="@style/TextColor"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="10dp"

                                android:text="@string/MySchool"
                                android:textSize="20dp"
                                tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                                android:background="@color/tranbackground"

                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                                tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Code without explanation isn't all that helpful - can you elaborate?